# Best way to check whether the instance of parent class rather than child class?

Tags: java, inheritance, instance

If I have a class A and a child class B extended from A, and I have an instance bbb of B from somewhere, what would be the best to check the instance bbb is not actually of A.

What I can think are the following two. Which is better or anything better than both of them?

1) if(!((bbb instanceof A) && (bbb instance of B)))

2) if(bbb.getClass().getName()!=A.class.getName()){

Thanks

Comment: Don't compare Strings with == or !=. Use the equals() method instead. Other than that, why don't you just try both and see what happens?

Comment: If B is subclass of A, you got a bbb (B's instance), it must be an instance of A too. or I misunderstood your question?

Comment: What's the real problem that you are trying to solve.  Whenever you think you need to test the class of a given object, you should ask yourself whether there is a better way to solve the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`bbb` actually is an instance of `A` since `B` extends `A`, so your first solution won't work.

Comparing the classes directly should suit your needs:

```
if (!A.class.equals(bbb.getClass()))
```

You could also think differently:

```
A bbb = ...;
if (bbb instanceof B) {
    // bbb has been instantiated via B or one of B subclasses
} else {
    // bbb has been instantiated via A or one of A subclasses except B
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's change A for Animal and B for Bird

I you already have an instance of Bird it can't possibly be a "raw" Animal. As Bird is a more specific type of Animal, JAVA won't let you directly assign a "raw" Animal into a Bird variable. If you meant the other way round (you have an Animal and you want to tell if it is actually a Bird) you can do it using

```
if ( bbb instanceof Bird) ...
```

In short, if your question is right, you can be sure you have a Bird without the need of checking anything.